# WPF - How to set Grid's children in a style?

Tags: wpf, styles

How can I do something like this?

```
<Style TargetType="Grid">
   <Setter Property="Children">
      <Setter.Value>
         ...
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

I know Children in read-only and this gives me "Writable property expected" on Children.

Thanks

Comment: Are you binding your grid items to anything?

Comment: Rachel, no I am not. Although styling in a form of binding. And that's why I think this doesn't work - since Children is not a DP, it cannot be used in bindings, and Styling is binding as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because `Panel.Children` is not a `DependencyProperty`. You almost certainly want to use an `ItemsControl` with a customized `ItemsPanel`. However, without more information I couldn't really say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ContentControl instead of Grid, and set its Template/ContentTemplate property with ControlTemplate/DataTemplate containing your Grid

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
           <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                 ...
                 </Grid>
                 </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

or

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
           <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
              <Setter.Value>
                 <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                 ...
                 </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```