# Change contents of a Border control with a Data Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Grid` named "Popup" that has its visibility bound to a `Bool` in the viewmodel using a `BoolToVisibilityConverter`.

This works perfectly, but I want to re-use it for multiple `UserControls` by setting the content of the `Border` control depending on another `Bool` in the viewmodel, also using a `BoolToVisibilityConverter`.

This is what I have so far but obviously it isn't working, and I can't find any answers online. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<Grid x:Name="PopUp" Visibility="{Binding ShowPopUp, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowView1}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ContentControl.Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <view:View1/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Border is no ContentControl, so you can't set a Content property.

Comment: Understood, but I can show a User Control in a Border , therefore there must be a way to set the content of the Border to a User Control through styles, and then triggers, right?

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the WPF online documentation. Declaring an element inside a Border in XAML sets the Border's Child property.

Comment: Okay, I understand that my method is not correct. However, I am still unsure  as to how to achieve the effect I am looking for. Could you suggest a suitable alternative?

Comment: Thank you @Clemens for the tip about setting the Border's Child property, it guided me to the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, using [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533586/wpf-how-to-set-grids-children-in-a-style) as inspiration.

I had to create a `ContentControl`, then used a `DataTrigger` to set the `Template` to a `Border` containing my `UserControl`, much in the same way that I was trying to do before.

```
<Grid x:Name="PopUp" Visibility="{Binding ShowPopUp, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowView1}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Border>
                                            <view:View1/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: just a note - there is another approach, see [Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) for details

Comment: If you want to switch between templates regarding your data, you can also use a DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look.